# Where can I get the ftpput source code?

Tags: linux, ftp

Where can I get the ftpput source code? I want to use it on embedded Linux. There is a ftpput command in BusyBox, but it does not support uploading a file to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the file `ftpgetput.c` from [Busybox sources](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/).

Comment: it does not support uploading a file to a directory.